# Exibir somente membros com um status em uma <select> com php pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

O que eu estou tentando fazer é selecionar todos os membros da tabela membros que tem o nome Lider na coluna "membro" exiba na select ordenado por nome.

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="selector1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Líder</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <select name="lider" id="lider" class="form-control1">
                                    <option value="SEM CÉLULA">SEM CÉLULA</option>
                                    <?php
                                    require_once("../cfg/base.php");
                                    $db=get_db();
                                    $stmt = $db-> prepare( 'SELECT membro, nome FROM membros WHERE membro = "Lider" ORDER BY nome' );
                                    $stmt-> execute();
                                    $result = $stmt-> fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
                                    ?>
                                    <?php foreach( $result as $row ) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['nome'];?>"><?php echo $row['nome'];?></option>
                                     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ok mas qual o problema que está dando?

Comment: Não exibe na select as pessoas que tem Lider na coluna membro da tabela membros

Comment: mas estão retornando do banco?

Comment: não tentei mostrar de outra forma e não está acontecendo

Comment: De um print_r($result); e veja se mostra algo, me fale se mostrar

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [membro] => Lider [nome] => Leonardo ) )

Comment: ok aqui nessa parte faça assim  <?php foreach( $result as $row ) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row[0]['nome'];?>"><?php echo $row['nome'];?></option>
                                     <?php } ?> Se der certo por favor me fale para mim colocar como resposta obrigado

Comment: funcionou mano, obrigado... coloca ai !

Comment: você poderia me ajudar com um aniversariantes do mes?

Comment: posso, mas como assim?

Comment: é que eu não tenho nem ideia de como fazer...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71913/discussion-between-anderson-henrique-and-leonardo-ribeiro).

Comment: deu erro aquele ultimo codigo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o index do array retornado assim

```
<?php foreach( $result as $row ) { ?> <option value="<?php echo $row[0]['nome'];?>"><?php echo $row['nome'];?></option> <?php } ?>
```